# MyBatis - Nested results are not updated after cache flush

Tags: java, caching, orm, mybatis

I have 2 mappers mapperA and mapperB.

mapperA have result map A which contains only result elements (simple properties) and is cached in own namespace.

mapperB have result map B which contains association to A (select statement findById) and is cached in own namespace too.

Problem is:

- `mapperB.findById` (loads B and the associated A - both gets cached)
- `mapperA.findById` (no select performed A is cached)
- `mapperA.update` (update some A - cache A gets flushed)
- `mapperA.findById` (select performed - loaded A is updated)
- `mapperB.findById` - here is the problem - no select is performed, because B is cached. But it is cached with the A instances. This instance do not reflect the update. There should be select / cache lookup performed to load current A instance.

**My question is:**

How can I make associations to work properly when both results are cached.

***Notes:***

I know that I can force A and B mapper to use single cache namespace so when A is updated it will flush all cached A and B queries. But consider that I have 10 A instances - these are being updated every few minutes. And 1 milion B instances - these are being updated once per day. Flushing all B's every time A gets updated is not efficient.

Comment: Do you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Sagar I haven't figured out any 'magical' solution. But one lesson I have learned is that sometimes it is easier not to use associations and just store ids of referenced objects. Then you could lookup these objects from cached DAO.

Answer (score 0):

You should use same-namespace cache.

in mapperA :

```
< mapper namespace="mapperA">

< cache/>
```

...

in mapperB :

```
< mapper namespace="mapperB">

< cache-ref namespace="mapperA"/>

...
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about this solution - see the Notes section of my question.